# How to sync react native app with express app?

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, synchronization, pouchdb

I am using react native android app for recording calls.Once the call get recorded, it should be uploaded to serer(express js and mysql) with call details.Suppose the app is in offline the file should uploaded to server whenever the app comes to online.How should i acheive this.

**NOTE:** All the above mentioned process should be run in background.

I found some solutions like pouchdb. For react native (*pouchdb-react-native*) npm and for express js (*express-pouchdb*) using this npm can i achive the sync? and how?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - using PouchDb server and LevelUp - to sync PouchDb with different backend databases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924263/is-it-possible-to-use-two-different-database-for-offline-web-application/46927234) for details and [the Nolan Lawson article](https://pouchdb.com/2014/07/25/pouchdb-levels-up.html) on LevelUp.